# Como puedo separar una cadena de string

Tags: java, string

necesito ingresar una fecha, que ingrese como string ejemplo: 21/10/2016-12:04, y estos datos convertirlos cada uno en un tipo de dato, ( int, byte),  para hacer validaciones y luego ingresarlos a un calendar

Comment: Hola Yeferson, gracias por la pregunta. Sugerencia: hubiera sido bueno que también compartieras tus intentos en resolver el problema (el código) y en qué aspectos *específicos* te ha costado llegar al objetivo. Se aprecia cuando hubo esfuerzo antes de hacer la pregunta. De lo contrario, parece que simplemente estás pidiendo que otros hagan el trabajo por ti.

Comment: @yerfeson-gallo si alguna respuesta resuelve tu problema, deberías marcarla como correcta por favor.

Answer (score 3):

Lo habitual para este caso concreto es usar un parseador de fechas, con el cual obtienes directamente un date que puedes emplear para inicializar el calendario que quieres obtener.

## Código

```
try {
    String fechaEntera = "21/10/2016-12:04";
    //transforma la cadena en un tipo date
    Date miFecha = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm").parse(fechaEntera);
    
    //creo un calendario
    Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
    //establezco mi fecha
    calendario.setTime(miFecha);

    //obtener el año
    int anio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    //obtener el mes (0-11 ::: enero es 0 y diciembre es 11)
    int mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    //obtener el dia del mes (1-31)
    int dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    //obtener el hora del dia (1-24)
    int hora = calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    //obtener el minuto
    int minuto = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    //obtener el segundo
    int segundo = calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    //...mas campos... 

} catch (ParseException ex) {
    //manejar excepcion
}
```

Se pueden obtener mas campos mirando las constantes de [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Comment: Buena respuesta. Quizás sería bueno agregar cómo obtiene cada uno de los valores.

Comment: @Mariano tienes razón, además lo comenta en la pregunta, lo añado.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes guardar la fecha como String e ir dividiendola mediante la función split.

```
String fechaEntera = "21/10/2016-12:04";
String[] fechaHora = fecha.split("-"); //Ahora tenemos un array de Strings tomando como referencia el -, es decir, con dos posiciones, en la primera estará almacenado la fecha y en la segunda la hora

String[] fechaDividida = fechaHora[0].split("/"); //Dividiremos la fecha (que está almacenada en la posición 0 del array anterior) tomando como referencia los `/`.
```

Y ya podremos mostrar la fechaDividida:

```
System.out.println(fechaDividida[0]); //21
System.out.println(fechaDividida[1]); //10
System.out.println(fechaDividida[2]); //2016
```

Ahora dividiremos la hora de la misma manera que la fecha pero tomando como referencia los dos puntos:

```
String[] horaDividida = fechaHora[1].split(":");
```

Y ya la podremos mostrar:

```
System.out.println(horaDividida[0]); //12
System.out.println(horaDividida[1]); //04
```

Por último, para pasar de String a int tendrás que usar la función parseInt:

```
int hora = Integer.parseInt(horaDividida[0]);
```

**EDIT:** Acabo de ver que lo que quieres es introducir estos valores en un Calendar. Para ello, podrás usar la función [set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).

```
calendar.set(anno, mes - 1, dia, hora, minutos, segundos);
```

A esta función le tendrás que pasar los datos enteros que acabas de calcular. Date cuenta de que el mes empieza con 0, es decir, el 0 es el equivalente a poner Enero. Ten cuidado con esto ya que si pones un 12 para diciembre te dará error (por eso le resto 1 al valor entero del mes que le pases).

Answer (score 0):

También existe el java.util.StringTokenizer que te permite separar la cadena a partir de los caracteres que le indiques. hay muchos ejemplos del uso de esto, solo tienes que buscar.

Comment: Cabe mencionar que la [documentación misma de `StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) no recomienda usar esta clase. Para los que entienden inglés, dice lo siguiente: *`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is __discouraged__ in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.*